# Custom Component run function before el is loaded, but before loaded event is emitted

Tags: aframe

I am writing a custom function that requires all components to be initialized (including itself).

Once all components are initialized, but before the loaded event is emitted, I want to run some custom logic over the el and then release the loaded event.

Is there a way to deal with this and is there a custom event like 'components-loaded'

I am trying to avoid the loaded event as it would interfere with other logic that requires this event while still monitoring the dom.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cool-component', {
  init: function() {
    this.preloadBound = this._preload.bind(this);
    this.el.addEventListener('components-loaded', this.preloadBound, {once: true});
    this.el.addEventListener('componentinitialized', this.preloadBound, {once: true});
    this.el.addEventListener('componentchanged', this.preloadBound, {once: true});
    this.el.addEventListener('componentremoved', this.preloadBound, {once: true});
    this.el.addEventListener('child-attached', this.preloadBound, {once: true});
    this.el.addEventListener('child-detached', this.preloadBound, {once: true});
    this.preloaded = false; <-- CREATED BOOL FLAG
  },
  _preload: function() {
    //do some work here
    this.preloaded = true;
  }
  exposed:function(){ <-- UPDATED THIS FUNCTION
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      if(!this.preloaded){
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.exposed().then(resolve);
        }, 200);
      }
      else{
        //do some work based on the work done in the preload
        resolve()
      }
    });
  }  
});
```

Comment: The only way I have managed to solve this is by making the exposed function return a promise, that validates the preload function has completed. in the event it has not completed, it then calls itself with the resolve using setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You could use events instead of a timer - emit an event when the preloaded stuff is done:

```
 _preload: function() {
  //do some work here
  emit('preloaded_done')
  this.preloaded = true;
},
exposed:function(){ 
  if (!this.preloaded) {
   this.el.addEventListener('preloaded_done', this.exposed)
   return;
  }
  // all things that are needed to be done after the preload
}
```

This way the exposed function will be executed after the preloaded stuff is done.

---

Or you could store the events in an array

```
init: function() {
  // ... binds and stuff
  this.cachedEvents = []
  this.el.addEventListener('loaded', this.cacheEvents)
  stuffBeforeEmittingEvents()
},
cacheEvents: function(e) {
  this.cachedEvents.push(e)
  this.el.removeEventListener(e.type, this.cacheEvents)
  e.stopPropagation()
}
```

and once You do your stuff, just loop through and emit them

```
for(i = 0; i < this.cachedEvents.length;  i++) {
    this.el.emit(this.cachedEvents[i].type, this.cachedEvents[i])
}
```

---

Something like this:

```
init: function() {
 this.events = []
 this.stuff = this.stuff.bind(this);
 this.cacheEvents = this.cacheEvents.bind(this);
 this.emitCachedEvents = this.emitCachedEvents.bind(this);

 this.el.addEventListener('loaded', this.cacheEvents)
 this.stuff()
},
stuff: function() {
  // whatever you need to do
  this.emitCachedEvents()
},
cacheEvents(e) {
 this.events.push(e)
 // prevent bubbling + catching the same event
 this.el.removeEventListener(e.type, this.cacheEvents)
 e.stopPropagation()
},
emitCachedEvents() {
   for (let i = 0; i < this.events.length; i++) {
      // primitive, may require polyfill - emit(name, data)
      emit(this.events[i].type, this.events[i])
   }
}
```

Check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16pb80rj/5/).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid deferring the loaded event as this would affect other parts of the system in ways I have not yet considered (and don't really want to think about).
I have updated my question to show my current solution using the Promise interface

Comment: @Beyerz I have another idea based on what i saw at Don McCurdys [physics system](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/blob/master/src/components/constraint.js#L53-L56).

Comment: I will definitely look into this library and take some pointers. I have already seen some aspects that will assist me.